# Canon MF4550d refuses to print from Linux server

Tags: linux, cups, printer, altlinux

We have several Canon mf4550d printers at the office directly connected to Windows 7 machines. I need to print from a Linux server to those printers.

I have installed the latest drivers for my model of printer. I've added the printer to CUPS through the web interface on `http://localhost:631`. All printer jobs are sending without any problems (no errors in log files), but the printer doesn't print.

Other printers, for example HP LaserJet 3055, work fine.
I guess it'd be connected with the port settings on the local machine, because canon has port settings as `usb001` but HP has `DOT4_0001`.

I tried to plug both printers into one computer and in the port settings of the Canon I changed `usb001` to `DOT4_001`. And then when I send printer jobs to the Canon my HP prints the following error:

> unable to open the initial device, quitting.

How can I resolve my problem?

My Linux server uses AltLinux 7.0.4 Centaurus (see its [cups](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/p7/srpms/cups) package).

Comment: Can you add a pointer/link to the drivers you are using?

Comment: http://www.canon.ru/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/Laser/LaserBase_MF_series/i-SENSYS_MF4550d.aspx?type=download&softwaredetailid=tcm:203-1135803&os=Linux&language=EN

Comment: Is there some reason you linked to a Russian page? Canon isn't a Russian company, afaik. I think it is Japanese. Do you have an English language page?

Comment: http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/Laser/LaserBase_MF_series/i-SENSYS_MF4550d.aspx?type=download&softwaredetailid=tcm:13-1135803&os=Linux&language=EN

Comment: I downloaded this. it's an exe file. I'm puzzled. How did you install it?

Comment: i opened it through 7-zip

Comment: here my logs https://yadi.sk/i/sG1QTglwW8ZFa

Comment: I can barely read that. Add it to the question, please. At the risk of stating the obvious, have you tried manufacturer-specific forums, if any?

Comment: I ran `7z e ...` on the downloaded `exe` file. It appeared to be unzipping fine, giving messages like ` Extracting uk_eng/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cndrvcups-common_2.80-1_amd64.deb `, but whnen I checked, /tmp/uk_eng is empty. Any idea?

Comment: Never mind, those files were being extracted to the current directory.

Comment: Can you say what driver you used, and what commands you executed, please? The most plausible ppd files look like CNCUPSMF4500WZK.ppd and CNCUPSMF4500ZK.ppd.

Comment: i tried each of them and another ones but it doesn't effect.(((

Comment: Can you give the relevant entry in `/etc/cups/printers.conf`? Also, please add the logs (again).